# How to make SpeechRecognizer run on main thread in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, speech-to-text

When a notification comes, it outputs it as a voice through TTS, and when the voice output ends, it implements a function that receives a voice input from the user and sends it as a message. So, I wrote the code to perform STT in the onDone function for the TTS object as follows and confirmed that the startSTT() function was executed.

```
class NotificationListener : NotificationListenerService() {

 private  fun startSTT() {
    val speechRecognizerIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH).apply {
        putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, packageName)
        putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
    }
    var speechRecognizer  = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this)
    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(recognitionListener())
    speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent)
}


private fun initTextToSpeech() {
    tts = TextToSpeech(this) {
        if (it == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            val result = tts?.setLanguage(Locale.KOREA)
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "language not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@TextToSpeech
            }
            tts?.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
                override fun onDone(utteranceId: String) {
                    startSTT()
                }

                override fun onError(utteranceId: String) {}
                override fun onStart(utteranceId: String) {}
            })
        }
    }

}
}
```

However, when executing the startSTT() function, the following error message occurs.

**SpeechRecognizer should be used only from the application's main thread**

How to modify the code to make SpeechRecognizer run on the main thread

Comment: Basically it's saying to run the code on ActivityMain which is the main thread. So I am not sure how you are calling it, but all that code needs to be moved to the ActivityMain then call everything from the main activity

Comment: I solved the problem by using looper and handler.